# need to rotate a square matrix by 90degree clockwise. works for 1st loop but gives index out of range the moment it enters next cycle

Tags: python, list, matrix, nested-loops, nested-lists

```py
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
        for i in range(0, len(matrix)//2):
            x = i
            y = len(matrix)-i-1
            for j in range(i,len(matrix)-i-1):
                prev = matrix[i][j]
                l = i
                r = j
                for k in range(1,5):
                    l = l + x
                    r = r + y
                    curr = matrix[l][r]
                    matrix[l][r] = prev
                    prev = curr
                    temp = x
                    x = y
                    y = temp*(-1)
                x = x + 1
                y = y - 1
```

```
input - [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

```
expected - [[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]]
```

output - [[7,2,1],[4,5,6],[9,8,3]]
(this result is if I stop j loop after 1st cycle. and if i let it go further it gives index error)

Comment: Please format the question

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use transposing operation (e.g. `zip(*iter)`) to simplify the code:

```py
def rotate_clockwise_inplace(m):
    m[:] = [list(reversed(t)) for t in zip(*m)]


m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

rotate_clockwise_inplace(m)
print(m)
```

Prints:

```
[[7, 4, 1],
 [8, 5, 2],
 [9, 6, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `numpy` alternative: [`np.rot90`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) for flexible 90 degrees rotation:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
out = np.rot90(arr, 1, axes=(1, 0))
```

---

```
array([[7, 4, 1],
       [8, 5, 2],
       [9, 6, 3]])
```